# JBoss stateless session bean as web service url

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x, java-ee-5

On JBoss 5.1.0, when I have an EJB3 stateless session bean exposed as a web service using the @WebService annotation in a jar it gets deployed successfully to the following url:
http://localhost:8080/SessionTest/MyBean

However, if I package the ejb jar in an EAR file it get's deployed to the following url:
http://localhost:8080/TestEAR-SessionTest/MyBean

i.e. Ear name - jar name as the context instead of just jar name.

Is there a way to specify the context that should be used (i.e. SessionTest) so that it is consistent regardless of whether it is deployed as a standalone ebj jar or in an EAR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@WebContext( contextRoot = "/webservices" )` to set the context root to a fixed location. 
There are more options, that are described in the [FAQ document](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-FAQ#How_do_I_know_what_endpoint_address_is_being_used).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Am going to use the jboss.xml file to define this rather than using a JBoss specific url, but this led me to the answer, cheers.

Comment: I meant JBoss specific annotation above.